# Leaked Window but want to finish activity when user click on positive button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I already read this: [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)
and some other post also.

This is the exception line: E/WindowManager:private android.view.WindowLeaked:void ActivitysaveMessage() com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivity{
 has leaked window DecorView@87ebe2a[AddReminderActivity] that was originally addedString heremessage = "";
        atif android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:534!isEditReminder)
    {

Exception:

```
E/WindowManager:private android.view.WindowLeaked:void ActivitysaveMessage() com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivity{
 has leaked window DecorView@87ebe2a[AddReminderActivity] that was originally addedString heremessage = "";
        atif android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:534!isEditReminder)
    {
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
       message at= android.view.WindowManagerImplgetResources().addViewgetString(WindowManagerImplR.java:94string.reminder_added_successfully);
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
} else {
      at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1125)
       message at= com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivitygetResources().saveMessagegetString(AddReminderActivityR.java:1179string.reminder_update_successfully);
        at com.tekitsolutions.remindme.Activity.AddReminderActivity.onResponse(AddReminderActivity.java:1547)
   reminderId = tempReminderId;
   at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        atnew android.os.Handler.handleCallbackAlarmReceiver(Handler).java:873cancelAlarm(this, reminderId);
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)}

        at androidandroidx.osappcompat.Looperapp.loop(LooperAlertDialog.java:201)
     Builder alertDialogBuilder = atnew androidandroidx.appcompat.app.Activit
```

My code:

```
private void saveMessage() {
        String message = "";
        if (!isEditReminder) {
            message = getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_added_successfully);
        } else {
            message = getResources().getString(R.string.reminder_update_successfully);
            reminderId = tempReminderId;
            new AlarmReceiver().cancelAlarm(this, reminderId);
        }

        androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.dialogBoxStyle);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("").setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                showLog("ARA: "+ reminderId);
                intent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, reminderId);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       if (!etTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setCancelable(false);
           builder.setMessage("Do you want to save Reminder?");
           builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
      }            
    }
```

Please try it. 
I hope it'll help you...!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying open a dialog after you exit an activity. In this case, the activity is being closed before the opening of the dialog

```
// remove below line
 super.onBackPressed(); 
from your onBackPressed() method
```

Comment: I still not understood. then where should I write the code? Let's say, I want to show a  dialog when user click back button.

Comment: try this @Override
    public boolean isFinishing() {  
        return super.isFinishing();

    }

Comment: or you can also try this remove line  super.onBackPressed(); from your onBackPressed() method

Comment: still is your issue not fixed?

Comment: for that back press it is solved, I just removed super statement, but now getting same exception here. I'm finishing activity when user click yes. what is wrong, I even

Comment: when I save details, I called save Message, and crashes on .show() method

Comment: do you have try with AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder instead of androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder

Comment: That is not a problem, I'm using somewhere else too.